# Scheme: adding 2 lists by index

Tags: list, recursion, scheme

I need to write a function in Scheme (Racket) that takes two not necessarily equal
length lists and return a list which each element is the sum of the elements of the same
index from the two lists. if the lists' length is not equal the shorter one should append to itself until it reaches the size of the longer one. for example:

```
=> (addLists '(1 2 3 4) '(1 2))
(2 4 4 6)

=> (addLists '(1 2 3 4) '(1 2 3 4 5))
(2 4 6 8 6)
```

Until now I was able to write a function that completes this for equal length lists, but the problem lies with how do I increase the length of the shorter list within this function (or with a helper function that gets a list and a size and extends it properly).

```
(define (sumListPairs lst1 lst2)
    (if (null? lst1) null
        (cons (+ (car lst1) (car lst2))
        (sumListPairs (cdr lst1) (cdr lst2)))))
```

Will appreciate any help, Thank you.

Comment: You might want to paste in the current definition of addLists that you have, that will help people help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done, but since I have the impression that this is a homework exercise, I'll only give a hint. First, introduce a named-`let` to do the actual recursion. Then, expand the number of cases in the recursion from two to four.

```
(define (sumListPairs lst1 lst2)
  (let loop ((l1 lst1) (l2 lst2))
    (cond ((and (null? l1) (null? l2)) null)
          ((null? l1) ...)
          ((null? l2) ...)
          (else (cons (+ (car lst1) (car lst2))
                      (loop (cdr l1) (cdr l2)))))))
```

Now, fill in the `...` parts. Note that you have access to all of `l1`, `l2`, `lst1` and `lst2`. (You might want to refactor a bit after you're done, since the cases will be quite similar.)

Comment: First question I posted, didnt know how to tag it as homework :)
Will try this solution!

Comment: @TomerBlu: you can't tag as homework anymore; you can just put it in the question (but it was clear enough from the problem description :)